# How can I loop a loop in py for a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, class, dictionary

So i tried defining a function in which the classroom's names would be generated as a dictionary.
But there seems to be an error in it and i can't find out what.

This is the syntax

```
def classroom():
    noofclass=int(input('Enter the number of classes:'))

    noofdivision=int(input('Enter the number of divisions: '))

    x={}
    for i in range(1,noofclass + 1):

        for j in range(1,noofdivision + 1):
            dict1={i:j}
            x.update(dict1)


    print(x)

classroom()
```

This is the output

```
Enter the number of classes:2
Enter the number of divisions: 2
{1: 2, 2: 2}
```

The division or subclasses for some reason dont take the values other than the value for 
 'noofdivision'.
Can you explain why and how to fix this error.

Comment: Could you give a full example of what's the input, what is your output and what is the expected output, please?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are unique - you can store only one value ``j`` for each key ``i``. *Please [edit] your question to clarify what output you expect.* Also note that instead of building a separate ``dict1`` and calling ``x.update``, you can directly assign ``x[i] = j``.

Comment: Any reason why you are avoiding the zero index? I feel like that is only going to make things more complicated later.

Comment: Well I’m avoiding the 0 index cuz these are subclasses of a class.like 1.1, 2.1 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a dictionary is a unique collection of keys, the second `j` iteration for each `i` overwrites the first iteration.

So for `i=1`, key `1` is created with value `1` and then, in the second iteration of `j` loop, the key `1` will be overwritten by `2`.

For your use case, `x` should be a `list` of `dicts`. Try:

```
def classroom():
    noofclass=int(input('Enter the number of classes:'))
    noofdivision=int(input('Enter the number of divisions: '))
    x=[]
    for i in range(1,noofclass + 1):
        for j in range(1,noofdivision + 1):
            x.append({i:j})
    print(x)

classroom() # output: [{1:1},{1:2}, {2:1}, {2:2}]
```

Comment: Why a ``list`` of ``dict``s? Dictionaries with a single key and value are generally unwieldy, since the value is not directly accessible. A ``list`` of tuples/namedtuples or a ``dict`` of ``list``s would seem more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I tried assigning a list value for x rather than a dict